# Обвернуть дивами цикл

Tags: php, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток! Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно обвернуть этот код http://pastebin.com/RQ58sHLU в бутстрап аккордеон http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: Я могу приободрить. Смелее пробуйте, у вас все получится!

Comment: Пробую 2 дня. Получается одна каша, как будто всё в одном аккордеоне :(

Comment: Тогда опубликуйте тот результат, который у вас сейчас есть, чтобы можно было ошибки найти.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VuJPKwjY вот весь мой корявый код :) А вот как получается http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1437328473/e10a161d/9329410.png Аренда ком. недвижимости должна находится в отдельном аккордеоне, а не вместе :)

Comment: боже мой, боже мой. Что я сейчас видел. Никогда не пишите такой код. Постоянно открывающиеся php теги просто раздражают.

Comment: Это такой код продают на Codecanyon :)